# Xcode files are not updating on Git Pull

Tags: swift, xcode, git, github

while pulling the code from GIT my files and folder in Xcode is not updating and it is showing in red.

I cloned the project again and deleted the old version but the problem still persist.

git log is showing the latest commit in the terminal

Here is the screenshot for same.[Here is the image  for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJoZB.png)

Comment: Can you see these folders in red in the actual project folder?

Comment: Folders are there but they are displaying old files only nothing updated from GIT pull too..

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: my Xcode version is 12.2 beta.

Comment: I tried to clone the project from GitHub too but the files are red too

Comment: Something is wrong. Have you checked GitHub and see if everything is there?

Comment: Yes all files are there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222085/discussion-between-rob-and-swapangeet).

Comment: sure Rob let us discuss